# Will the same set of variables perform best for all classifying methods?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

Suppose that out of a large set of attributes, S, that describe the target variable M, there exists a subset Z of S that optimize the performance for say a decision tree model, does that mean that Z will optimize performance for all other techniques, such as K-NN , or Bayes, or SVM?

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not generally hold.

Some of the methods have built-in feature selection, too.